# Image Button with Link to other view

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

i'm working with .NET Maui and i'm using image buttons to redirect to other views. Now I have a simple button for the profile, and I want the button to redirect to the view (XAML-File) on click. How can I do this? What I have so far is this:

Profile Template (/Views/Profile.XAML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Profile"
             x:Class="Project.Views.Profile"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Profile"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my Image button:

```
<ImageButton Source="circle.png" Clicked="OnImageButtonClicked" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
```

code behind:

```
void OnImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

What can I do to redirect to the profile view on click?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Which View do you want to navigate to from where?

Comment: have you read the docs on Navigation?  There are multiple examples of the different ways to navigate between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate from a Content page to another content page, you can use the following code:

```
var nextPage = new NextPage (); 
await Navigation.PushModalAsync (nextPage);
```

Or

```
var nextPage = new NextPage (); 
await Navigation.PushAsync (nextPage);
```